# Creating array of numbers from 0 to n for positive and negative n

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given `n`, I want to create an array from `0` to `n`:

```
10.make_array #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

It should also work if `n` is negative:

```
-10.make_array #=> [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

I have written this code, but I think I made it more complicated than necessary (it doesn't work for negative numbers, yet):

```
class Fixnum
  define_method(:make_array) do
    my_array = []
    self.times() do |count|
      self.>(0)
      my_array.push(count)
    end
    my_array.push(self)
    my_array
  end
end
```

Is there an easier way or short-cut to do the same thing, and any suggestions on how to handle a negative number?

Comment: What is the expected result when a negative number is given?

Comment: @sawa, Thanks for the edit. The expected result would be to create an array from 0 - n, where n is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support negative numbers, you could use [`upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html#method-i-upto) and [`downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html#method-i-downto) along with a condition:

(I'm showing a stand-alone method here instead of patching `Integer`)

```
def make_array(n)
  if n > 0
    0.upto(n).to_a
  else
    0.downto(n).to_a
  end
end
```

The above creates an enumerator that's converted to an array using [`Enumerable#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

You might want to skip the intermediate object (the enumerator) by directly calling [`Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-c-new) - it creates an array with the given number of elements:

```
n = 3
Array.new(n) #=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

If a block is given, it passes each element's index to the block and we are supposed to returns its value. The *index* is in fact just what we want, so we can simply return it:

```
Array.new(n) { |i| i } #=> [0, 1, 2]
```

As you can see, `Array.new(n)` returns `n` elements, but we need `n + 1`, so let's fix that:

```
Array.new(n + 1) { |i| i } #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Unfortunately, `Array::new` doesn't accept a negative size:

```
Array.new(-3) #=> negative array size (ArgumentError)
```

So for negative `n` we have to pass `-n` and also return `-i`:

```
n = -3
Array.new(-n + 1) { |i| -i } #=> [0, -1, -2, -3]
```

As a method:

```
def make_array(n)
  if n > 0
    Array.new(n + 1) { |i| i }
  else
    Array.new(-n + 1) { |i| -i }
  end
end
```

Let's try to avoid the duplication.

Converting `n` to a positive number is easy using [`abs`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Numeric.html#method-i-abs):

```
3.abs  #=> 3
-3.abs #=> 3
```

Applied to our code:

```
n = 3
Array.new(n.abs + 1) { |i| i } #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]

n = -3
Array.new(n.abs + 1) { |i| i } #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

For the block, we could use a [ternary `if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if):

```
n = 3
Array.new(n.abs + 1) { |i| n > 0 ? i : -i } #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]

n = -3
Array.new(n.abs + 1) { |i| n > 0 ? i : -i } #=> [0, -1, -2, -3]
```

We can even remove the condition by using the spaceship operator `a <=> b`. It determines whether `a` is less than, equal to, or greater than `b` by returning `-1`, `0` or `+1`, respectively.

More specifically, for [`Fixnum#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), `n <=> 0` returns `1` if `n` is greater than `0`, and `-1` if `n` is less than `0`:

```
3 <=> 0  #=> 1
-3 <=> 0 #=> -1
```

We can use `<=>`'s result in our block to multiply `i` with:

```
Array.new(n.abs + 1) { |i| i * (n <=> 0) }
```

This is equivalent to `i * 1` (if `n > 0`) or `i * -1` (if `n < 0`).

(There's a third return value: `n <=> 0` returns `0` if `n` is equal to `0` but that doesn't matter, because in that case the resulting array is `[0]` and `0 * 0` is still `0`)

As a method:

```
def make_array(n)
  Array.new(n.abs + 1) { |i| i * (n <=> 0) }
end
```

Although it is short, this method became quite complex and it's not obvious what is is doing. Therefore, I would prefer the first method (the one using `upto` and `downto`) because of its simplicity.

Comment: My god this is beautiful. The amount of time you put into explaining this is mind blowing. You should write a book for beginners since you definitely cover all the angles of explaining why something is happening. I didn't even know about .downto...brilliant. How many years did it take you to get this good?

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

```
(0 .. 10).to_a
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Handling negative numbers is not a problem:

```
(-10 .. -1).to_a
#=> [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ruby Array method.

`Array.new(11) {|i| i} #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

The first argument is the number of elements that you want to create, and you can use the block to define what will go in each item.

More examples:

`Array.new(10) #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`

`Array.new(3) {5} #=> [5, 5, 5]`

`Array.new(8) {|i| i * 2} #=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]`

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code: `[*1..10]`

Answer (score 1):

Following your intent to add this to `Fixnum`

```
class Fixnum
  define_method(:make_array) do
    Array.new(self + 1) {|i| i}
  end
end

p 3.make_array      # => [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

With negative numbers this will throw an exception, except for -1 which will yield an empty array.

**ADDENDUM**

After noting sawa's edit regarding handling negative numbers, the following works:

```
class Fixnum
  define_method(:make_array) do
    self < 0 ? Array.new(-self + 1) {|i| -i} : Array.new(self + 1) {|i| i}
  end
end

-5.make_array     # => [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```

Comment: Excellent! This format is what I was looking for. I'm not far enough along to utilize any of the other answers submitted. I experience this a lot, where the tools I'm able to use are limited based on what I'm familiar with so what seems easy to more experienced guys is simply outside of my ability to work with.

Comment: Happy to help.  Enjoy rubying!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Fixnum
  def sequence_from_zero
    0.step(self, self/self.abs).to_a
  end
end

p 10.sequence_from_zero  # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
p -10.sequence_from_zero # => [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Fixnum#upto`:

```
$ ruby -e "p 1.upto(10).to_a"
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```